# How to make text field non editable in Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs4, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have used the following properties to make an textfield and disable it for user edit.

**disabled: true**

below is my code for the Xtype decleration.

```
xtype : 'passwordfield',
name : 'password',
id: 'password',
disabled: true,
label : 'Password',
placeHolder :'Password',
useClearIcon : false
```

it appears something as shown in below image.  The label is grayed out. Please let me know how can i make it non-editable and label will remain same.

[image]

**Edit-1:**
After, Couple of searches in Stack overflow and sencha forum i have found the below code which is able to make my text field non-editable but now it is static in nature.

```
 listeners: {
            afterrender: function(ele) {
                     ele.fieldEl.dom.readOnly = true;
          }
     }
```

**We can set the property one time, but it doesn't have any method to set dynamically. I need dynamically as i have to sometimes make user to edit and sometimes to make it.** disabled.

Any other approach to make text field non editable in Sencha Touch is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting with `fieldEl.dom.readOnly` is not really static as most people think, because the readOnly flag is not a Sencha-specific option. That means: You save your item you want to make read-only and change its status dynamically, then add another control which sets `fieldEl.dom.readOnly` to false, and voila, your item is editable again.

Answer (score 9):

```
readOnly: true
```

thx, that works fine for me. now i can use a textfield like a label. using a simple field was causing problem with formpanel.data

Answer (score 5):

### Update

`readOnly` should be part of initial settings eg:

```
xtype : 'passwordfield',
name : 'password',
id: 'password',
disabled: true,
label : 'Password',
placeHolder :'Password',
useClearIcon : false,
readOnly: true
```

---

Use `readOnly` :

```
readOnly: true
```

Comment: .this has not effect, i have tried this also. I have edited my question take a look at the updated edit section.

Comment: also we dont have any readonly property for Ext.form.Text class.

Comment: @Neel is the readOnly or readonly property working for you? Case sensitive has no effect. I just use disabled:true

Comment: u can also use listeners: {
            afterrender: function(ele) {
                     ele.fieldEl.dom.readOnly = true;
          }
     }

Comment: Also tried that. I see now. Your talking about sencha touch 1? I Got confused by the sencha-touch-2 tag.. Tnx anyway!